# Are Bob Benson's collected political articles accessible in either print or online?

Tags: resource, journalism

A journalist by the name of Bob Benson is cited by [Bill Rowe](https://www.google.ee/search?tbo=p&tbm=bks&q=inauthor:%22William%20Neil%20Rowe%22) in at least one of his books. As I've read all of his political books, none of them have an ebook preview, and the index in none of these books refers to Bob Benson, I'm not sure in which one of these books I first came across the name. However, the gist of it was that Bob Benson was a gifted journalist, primarily covering Newfoundland's provincial politics. Specifically, Bill Rowe suggested that Benson be used as a primary source in understanding the development of N&L's provincial politics.

**Are Bob Benson's collected political articles accessible in either print or online?**

I've searched on the St John's 'Telegram', Wikipedia (no mention of Bob Benson *in general*), Google, and Google Books without any luck. The St John's 'Telegram' does not seem to have an online archive. Also, while, presumably, the articles still exist in individual copies of daily papers, that is not an 'accessible' source as it would entail ordering all of the copies for each newspaper issue for someone without direct access to a library which stocked the newspaper—if indeed any does which I've also been unable to prove).

Nevertheless, Google comes up with [a few references to Benson](https://www.nlhistory.ca/publication/confederation/) and some uses of his articles as sources, e.g., [here](https://books.google.ee/books?id=YixStndEudYC&pg=PA279&lpg=PA279&dq=%22bob%20benson%22%20newfoundland&source=bl&ots=9TI0rhcB7I&sig=ACfU3U0fW0BnGS_PjKSgnOxh2ORrHbGNxA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiC-cqDm-rpAhXdwcQBHREZD5EQ6AEwAHoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22bob%20benson%22%20&f=false), [here](https://books.google.ee/books?id=o-cN-Ulw360C&pg=PA246&lpg=PA246&dq=%22bob%20benson%22%20newfoundland&source=bl&ots=gOL6tFtDEu&sig=ACfU3U1-Q5VRE_s5J5qi5JGiWwk1RaL17Q&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiC-cqDm-rpAhXdwcQBHREZD5EQ6AEwBHoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22bob%20benson%22%20newfoundland&f=false), and [here](https://books.google.ee/books?id=n5__t0HBUhwC&pg=PA271&lpg=PA271&dq=%22bob%20benson%22%20newfoundland&source=bl&ots=7lN_xH4x4O&sig=ACfU3U1vWFxTAx57AH98qmM5558j2M5buQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiC-cqDm-rpAhXdwcQBHREZD5EQ6AEwAnoECAUQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22bob%20benson%22%20newfoundland&f=false), primarily from the 1980's and 1990's.

PS. The Meta case for a question such as this [is hopefully made here](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2236/should-some-requests-for-resources-be-on-topic). Please note that despite my research, I've not been able to prove [whether a singular answer exists](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2277/16201) as asked by that answer in the topic.

Comment: Looks like a good question to ask the [Centre for Newfoundland Studies](https://www.library.mun.ca/forms/nlquestion/).